# How to fix slow query performance using NOT EXISTS MySQL? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to optimize / speed up the performance the loading of my data, is there a way to fix this?

I have 3 tables involved:

`tbl_tt_college_studentpersonalinfo` - This table displays the name of students, it is join in my query

`tbl_tt_college_preenrollment` - This table displays the pending status of pre-enrolled students

`tbl_tt_college_enlistment` - This table will check the existing record the student has.

Here is my Query: - The problem that I am having is the load of data is slow, it may take 30-50 seconds. Is there a way to improve this or make it like a join query?

```
public function get_enlists()
{
    $this->db->join('tbl_tt_college_studentpersonalinfo','tbl_tt_college_preenrollment.studentID = tbl_tt_college_studentpersonalinfo.studentID');
    $this->db->where('tbl_tt_college_preenrollment.departmentID', $this->input->post('course'));
    $this->db->where('tbl_tt_college_preenrollment.yearLevel', $this->input->post('yearLevel'));
    $this->db->where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT tbl_tt_college_enlistment.studentKeyID FROM tbl_tt_college_enlistment WHERE tbl_tt_college_enlistment.studentKeyID = tbl_tt_college_preenrollment.studentKeyID AND schoolYear = '" . $this->session->userdata('currentAcademicYear') . '-' . ($this->session->userdata('currentAcademicYear') + 1) . "' AND semester =     '" . $this->session->userdata('currentSemester') . "')");
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_tt_college_preenrollment');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Here is the raw query for the reference:

```
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT studentKeyID FROM tbl_tt_college_enlistment 
    WHERE tbl_tt_college_studentpersonalinfo.studentKeyID = tbl_tt_college_enlistment.studentKeyID 
    AND schoolYear = '" . $this->session->userdata('currentAcademicYear') . '-' . ($this->session->userdata('currentAcademicYear') + 1) . "'                            
    AND semester =  '" . $this->session->userdata('currentSemester') . "'
)
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on tables? Rather than `NOT EXISTS` as a subquery, left join to `tbl_tt_college_preenrollment`, `where tbl_tt_college_enlistment.studentKeyID IS NULL`

Comment: @danblack - hello sir, indexes used is `studentKeyID` for all tables

Comment: @danblack - is there a way to do it in active record for the left join subquery? can you please give me an example, sir?

Comment: @danblack - should I still include the `NOT EXISTS` on the query or replace it with left join?

Comment: try using JOINS in `tbl_tt_college_enlistment`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam - I have already tried, it is fetching certain columns only but not all.

Comment: @capstonebidapp - "it is fetching certain columns only but not all" -- show us the entire generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

See if this composite index on `tbl_tt_college_enlistment` helps:

```
INDEX(schoolYear, semester, studentKeyID)
```

If not adequate, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`